# Get width of a button using JS?

Tags: javascript, button, resize

I have a button inside index.html, created inside the html file NOT the javascript file. I am trying to get the width of the button using pure Javscript. I am not using jQuery not will that or any other JS library be an option. What I have tried:

```js
  function resizeButtom() {
        var btn = document.getElementById('btn-resize-me');
        alert(btn.style.width); // alerts blank
        alert(parseInt(btn.style.width); // alerts NaN, because the value is a blank
        btn.style.width = toString(parseInt(btn.style.width) - 20) + "px"; // does not work!
    }
```

```html
<button id="btn-resize-me" onClick="resizeButton();"></button>
```

stylesheet.css

```
.menu-btn {
    background-color: #F3F2F1;
    border: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 7px 12px 7px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width:auto;
}
```

I cannot set the button width because it is a sum of the width of the font that is loaded on the browser (the default font might not load on a specific brower) and 14px, 7px padding on left and right side.

MOTIVATION:
When I press a button I want another button to get a border of 1px solid black. This is works perfect, but then the button is 2px bigger in width because of the border, shifting the other menu item buttons by 2px, which looks weird. I though resizing the changed button (now with border: 1px solid black;) by 2px would solve this. The answers give a way to resize but it approximates, resulting in a new size, keeping padding and looking unnatural and ugly.

Comment: You spelled `resizeButton` wrong, and you need an extra `)` at line 4 of the Javascript.

Comment: add the code which set width of btn by font size and padding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve it with `offsetWidth` , also for set width of that btn you don't need `toString` :
Update : Added changing font size of button.

```js
function resizeButton() {
        var btn = document.getElementById('btn-resize-me');
        alert(parseInt(btn.offsetWidth)); 
        btn.style.width = (parseInt(btn.offsetWidth) - 20)+"px";  btn.style.fontSize = "12px";
 alert(parseInt(btn.style.width)); 
    }
```

```css
#btn-resize-me {
    background-color: #F3F2F1;
    border: 1ox solid gray;;
    color: black;
    padding: 7px 12px 7px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width:auto;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn-resize-me"  onClick="resizeButton()">hello</button>
```

Comment: I cannot set width because it depends on the users web browser and how it displays the font / text. The current width is the font size width + 14px because of 7px padding on left and right side.

Comment: @RealAnwersOnly but somehow it has to be set for test here. :)

Comment: @RealAnwersOnly just test above code without set width and it would works.

Comment: I have the code above in my website and it does not work. That is why I asked the question @Mohammad. Not setting width results in a blank when trying to access the width. A blank is not a number. I can therefor not get the width of the button.

Comment: Sorry that is correct! However the issue with the above code is that the text inside the button no longer is centered, the width is just being pulled to the left (getting smaller, and closer to the button text). This looks ugly and is not what I am looking for. Also I have text-align: center. ALSO: the inital width for the text is 14.213 but after making it smaller and then larger, the widht is not 14.213 anymore.

Comment: @RealAnwersOnly based the information you gave i tried my best. if you think more informatiin is needed so you can edit your question and add more info.
i hoped my answer helps and works :)

Comment: @RealAnwersOnly you  easily can change font-size or any other attribute after button get smaller. check my code. I've updated it again ! :)

Comment: changing the font size is not ideal in this situation, that would also look weird and be unintuitive.

Comment: i wish i could understand what is your goal. anyway i don't update my answer anymore, i hope it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function resizeButton() {
    var btn = document.getElementById('btn-resize-me');
    alert(btn.offsetWidth); // alerts 
    btn.style.width = Math.max(btn.offsetWidth - 20, 0) + "px"; // works
    //the width is reduced by about 20, until it can't
}
```

```html
<button id="btn-resize-me" onClick="resizeButton();" style="width: auto; overflow: hidden;">Some Text</button>
```

Comment: I cannot set width because it depends on the users web browser and how it displays the font / text. The current width is the font size width + 14px because of 7px padding on left and right side.

Comment: You can set the width, to something bigger than the width of the web browser that displays the widest. You could use `initial` to set to the default width, but then when you get the width you can't subtract it. Also, making the width less than default will cut off the text.

Comment: when I set the button to something bigger than the widht of the web browser I get a broken website. Setting initial vaule is pointless in this example because I want to edit the width.

Comment: that answer will, after about 5 presses of the button, make the width of the button 0 which results in the button on the right of said button be directly next to the text inside said button. This is absolutely not what my users wants to experience.

Comment: You need to remove the padding in order for it to be fully zero. Otherwise, you could delete/hide the element.

Comment: Deleting or hiding it would be really really weird. Deleting the padding would result in weird UI. Getting the padding and resizing it is also not working. I have set the padding as such: `padding: 7px 12px 7px` but am unable to get the padding via `btn.style.padding`

Comment: Did you set the padding inside the html element open tag? `btn.style.padding` does not work if the padding is defined in separate CSS.